Why does convolutional neural network use a 2d Filter
Given an input of C,H,W where C is channels the filter is of size X,Y and slides across each channel individually. Why isn't the filter of size C,X,Y and slides across the entire 3d shape?
I know of the existence of 3D convolutions but I don't think this is what it is.
